# on coming back to fragment ArrayList getting empty (restore ArrayList)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, restore, savestate

first onClick in Monday_fragment it adds the data to ArrayList. 
Second OnClick in Monday_fragment it takes to Monday_list_fragment where the list is shown. There is a button in Monday_list_fragment which brings it back to the Monday_fragment.
I debugged an seen, when i came back all the data in ArrayList is gone. 
How to keep the ArrayList data not to clear out on coming back.

**Codes**

**Monday_fragment**
https://github.com/tirthoguha/DroidProject/blob/myDiary/src/com/example/s0217980_diary/Monday_fragment.java

**Monday_list_fragment**
https://github.com/tirthoguha/DroidProject/blob/myDiary/src/com/example/s0217980_diary/Monday_list_fragment.java

Answer (score 1):

When the fragment is started, it creates a new, empty list. In the first `onClick` in `Monday_fragment`, it replaces the list with one created from `entryLogs`. When you return from `Monday_list_fragment`, the `onCreate` method is called, and the list and entryLogs are overwritten with new, empty ones.

The `onCreate` method can be called multiple times, including when the device orientation changes. You need to rethink how and when you set up the state of your fragment.

Comment: if i make the ArrayList Static and and initialise in the MainActivity, will that help. I wonder, then in OnCrete it won't get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

dude I am just continuing form the [que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103028/pass-arraylist-from-fragment-to-another-fragmentextends-listfragment-using-bun/23149170#23149170). If you have done same as you posted code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103028/pass-arraylist-from-fragment-to-another-fragmentextends-listfragment-using-bun/23149170#23149170), just paste this line in `onCreateView` of `Monday_fragment`.

```
 myStringList= MainActivity.getMyStringList();
```