# Would this be the correct way to access an arraylist from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, oncreate

Just need to know the proper syntax to accessing an array that was created in a different class.

```
public class item_fragment extends Fragment {

 ArrayList<MyItems> mylist;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



         mylist =   ((MyApplication)  getActivity().getApplication()).getItemsArrayList();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_work_item_fragment,container, false);
}//ends onCreate View
}
```

Comment: Keeps telling me the size is 0.

Comment: Where was it created? Could you grab it from the host Activity instead?

Comment: I could pass the array of objects through the intent but I thought passing the index was much easier because once I have the index I could access the array from my next activity.

Comment: It might not be the best way to do that, but that'll totally work. If it says your array size is 0 odds are very good if you posted the rest of the code it really *would* be zero. Note if this were the wrong way to do it, it would have said it is null and crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a look at [Pass ArrayList from fragment to another fragment(extends ListFragment) using bundle, seListAdapter runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103028/pass-arraylist-from-fragment-to-another-fragmentextends-listfragment-using-bun?rq=1)

This includes

> One thing if you read your code carefully, you have declared ArrayAdapter in Monday_fragment, so this list initialize every time when you replace this fragment with other. So just create a ArrayAdapter in MainActivity and getter, setter for the same and change your methode ArrayList toStringList(Collection entryLogs) in the Monday_fragment like below

Answer (score 0):

That will work fine. Except as a caveat. This might well be called before your activity is created. If you look at the fragment lifecycle you'll see.

The core series of lifecycle methods that are called to bring a fragment up to resumed state (interacting with the user) are:

```
onAttach(Activity) called once the fragment is associated with its activity.
onCreate(Bundle) called to do initial creation of the fragment.
onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.
onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().
onViewStateRestored(Bundle) tells the fragment that all of the saved state of its view hierarchy has been restored.
onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).
onResume() makes the fragment begin interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).
```

You will note that onViewCreated can easily predate the activity created. As such if you say re-initialize that array, your fragment would have an empty array that never got anything added to it. Or if you checked the size before the onActivityCreated() is called you would still have 0 array size assuming you give the array values after it's done initializing.